# How to copy gnote(s) from a computer to another one on Red Hat?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

My organization requires me to switch to a new remote machine. So I am in the process of transferring my data.

I'd like to transfer my gnote(s) but on disk I can only find the settings:

```
.gconf-lts-redhat/apps/gnote/%gconf.xml
```

There seems to be the answer on Red Hat but I don't have a paid account there:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1321553

Notice that the location suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/51095/how-can-i-sync-gnote-notes does not exist on Red Hat.

Notice also that I cannot use GNote synchronization because it is disabled by my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought...

The notes are stored in ~/.gnote

So it is sufficient to copy the folder with your preferred mode. I used scp:

```
scp -r .gnote <target machine>
```

However, GNote on the target machine did not detect automatically the new notes. I figured out that I needed to refresh/restart it. Since I could not restart the machine (job server) I just killed and restarted the process. I am sure that there are more elegant ways, but it worked :)

```
ps aux | grep gnote
kill <the gnote pid>
```

GNote is smart enough to detect the shutdown and open a dialog providing an option to reload the gnome panel where gnote was loaded. After that, my notes appeared!